# MYSQL: Want to make a date column NULL

Tags: mysql, django, null, alter-table

I have some changes to a Django app using a mysql database backend. I have been receiving this error.

`(1048, "Column 'current_item_status_date' cannot be null")`

I have tried to make it NULL by using the ALTER TABLE command, but this is not working. Saying there is an invalid syntax.

`ALTER TABLE tiptop_items MODIFY current_item_status_date null;`

Comment: You should also specify field data type in your statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE tiptop_items MODIFY current_item_status_date DATE NULL;
```